# Block file upload dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following issue.

I have an aspx file upload input that must only show the file dialog if certain text field has a value, otherwise I must simply show an alter saying to fill the field.

I cannot use jquery.

Comment: jquery is just javascript. it just makes things easier, but doesn't do anything you couldn't do yourself with barebones what-you-get-with-the-browser javascript.

Comment: I know, but the buzz says I cannot use jquery because the client wants to live in the stone age.

Comment: What have you tried? I can tell you right now that if the file selector is disabled the dialog wont appear.

Comment: Simply to disable the upload input, but they specifically want it to not be disabled as to not confuse the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event object has a [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) function that you can use to stop the default from continuing. Using this you can attach a click event to your file upload which will fire upon trying to select a file. From there you can check the value of your text input and return/stop the default of the file element.

```
(function() {
  var __file = document.getElementById('file');
  var __text = document.getElementById('required');

  __file.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if ( __text.value.length === 0 )
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      return alert('Please fill out the textbox!');
    }


  })
})()
```

Note: Only tested this in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! I will test it out and report later.